# Exporting shapefile to DWG

Tags: shapefile, export, java, geotools, dwg

I need export a shapefile to DWG using Java.

I have seen many examples of how to export a DWG file to PDF, but I have not found any that directly export from shapefile to DWG .

Is it possible to do this with GeoTools? If not possible, is there another way to do it?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7639855/generating-autocad-files-with-java